# How to Create Instant Chat App in android like whatsapp and hike with simple ui

Tags: java, android, xml, chat

Frnds I am newer to android trying to create android chat app like whatsapp and i dont know the way or starting point how to create and what to study. Please help me to learn and implement chat application for android.
The app Must be based on google cloud messaging.

Comment: anything means? i studied about basics of android layout and functionalities permissions..

Comment: You need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Your question comes out to be very broad which is not how things work here. Thats why you got downvotes. I suggest you to first plan this app, how you are going to make and then start with the coding part.

Comment: ok let me try and can u suggest any tutorial websites or blog

Comment: start with the basics of android, www.vogella.com/,  www.androidhive.info, plan first, wire frame and then start the coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn Java first, how to write Server applications and how TCP/IP works.
When you can look at the special aspects of Android.

There are many free programming related books for all topics on [this Github page](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md).